# Is my processor too hot?

Tags: cpu, fan, temperature

I just recently built my desktop computer and I noticed that my APU (Accelerated Processing Unit) is getting around like 66C - 78C when I just leave it at the desktop but when I play a game (I was playing Castlevania Lord of Shadows 2 on max everything) and the I checked my highest temperature over a 30min period and the highest temperature it reached around that time was 95C

I have a 140mm fan and a 120mm fan on top of my computer and a 120mm fan below my computer and a 120mm fan in front of my computer. As I just recently built my computer so the thermal paste is still good and I have all the fans running about 2000rpms. My processor is a AMD 10-7870 (which has integrated graphics but they should be automatically disabled)

Comment: Are your fans limited to 2k rpm? Yes, those temps are high, but you should research your specific CPU model for it's acceptable operating range. But most fans should be capable of running higher than 2k rpm, especially if you allow the BIOS to control them. Further, the air can only cool if it is itself cool. Make sure the PC case intake fans have access to well-circulated cool air and aren't, for instance, ingesting air directly from a heater vent.

Comment: My fan speed is set to turbo and the air in the room is some what cool but I recorded my temperature in the background and just from watching youtube my highest temp jumped to 90c. And I changed one of the fans because its fastest speed on turbo was around 950rpm but now all 4 (not including the cpu fan) reaches around 2000rpm except for 1 (which isn't the one i replaced) which is around 17K rpm

Fan1: Around 2k rpm
Fan2: Around 2k rpm

Comment: I also forgot to mention that all the parts (except for the cpu fan and motherboard) are used parts, my older brother gave me his parts when he upgraded his pc but that really doesn't make a difference right?

Comment: I got the temperature to go down and when I use about maybe 10-30% of my processor the temp is around high 60s low 70s but apparently when playing skyrim special edition over 2 hour period my highest temp that my processor got was 95c. Also now when I just sit at the desktop its around 50C, a big problem was my fans, they didn't have good airflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some details on the specific CPU model and mainboard you're using would be more helpful, but absent those, the general steps for cooling issues are these:

As noted earlier: make sure the air going into the CPU is not direct from a heat source, but is from free room air.

Set your BIOS fan settings to Automatic, and if you can, set a preference to keeping things cooler rather than quieter.

Make certain your BIOS is fully updated as well as any mainboard and CPU drivers in the OS.

I did a bit of research and it turns out 2000 RPM is not abnormal among 1200mm and "silent", so that is not something to worry about in your case.

However, while you note the thermal paste is properly applied, since you're having this issue and based on the information you've added in comments, you should take your CPU fan off, clean and reapply thermal paste using the manufacturers directions, and reinstall the CPU fan. If you're using an aftermarket CPU cooler, you may want to make sure it is appropriate for the CPU you're using and the way you're using it.

From what I've been able to tell, the temps you report are quite high for AMD CPUs, and AMD CPUs have been known to have temp issues which will damage the die, so resolving this is important if you want a long-lasting and stable computer.

UPDATE: Adding info from comments

If you have made sure all of your cooling components are working as they are designed to, some other considerations are to make sure the cooling components are actually designed to work together.

CPU coolers are typically designed to work with a specific few models of CPU, usually within a specific processor family.

Sometimes there will be brackets and other hardware that allow the cooler to work across a range of CPUs, but sometimes the cooling capability of the cooler is tuned for a specific CPU's heating characteristics.

In order to support a CPU, among other things the mainboard must place mounting piece (holes for screws, mounting brackets, etc) in locations specified by the CPU maker.

If the mounting holes on your mainboard do not match those of the cooler, that indicates that cooler may not be designed to work with that CPU, or, even if it is, it will not be placed correctly to transfer heat correctly and cooling will not be correct.

You can do further research on your existing CPU cooler to see if it even supports your CPU, and if so, see if you can get replacement mounting hardware that is correct for it, or if not, it is highly recommended that you find a CPU cooler (it doesn't have to be liquid) that is actually designed to work with your CPU.

Comment: The noise of the fan really isn't a problem I could honestly care less and my motherboard is an asus a88x-pro and I don't have a cpu I have an APU "AMD 10-7870" and also I have 3 1200mm fans and 1 1400mm fan

Comment: "APU" is marketing speak and essentially meaningless. Every PC contains a Central Processing Unit, a "CPU". If AMD wished to call theirs an Asparagus, that's great for them, but it doesn't change the fact that it is really a CPU.

Comment: Silent fans are fans designed to run quietly, not simply fans that are being run quietly. They will typically be larger in diameter and run at lower RPM. The RPM is typically hard-limited by the construction of the fan. A fan that runs at 2000RPM +/- 10% can only physically operate between 1800RPM and 2200RPM, when given the current provided by a normal connection.

Comment: Used components could be damaged or inefficient components. Performing the steps I've provided above will help determine whether the components themselves need to be replaced or not.

Comment: They aren't damaged parts and they are pretty efficient and I was being specific with my processor thats why I said APU and not CPU because even though it does have a CPU it also has integrated graphics. Also I just decided to turn off the q-control because as I said before I could honestly care less about the noise of the fans

Comment: Good to hear the components are OK. I hate to beat a dead horse, but lots of CPUs have integrated graphics too, and they're still called CPUs. So turning off the Q Control (I assume that means telling your BIOS you don't care if the machine is quiet or not) resolved the issue enough? It still sounds as though the cooling components are not enough for your system, if they are working correctly, but have to run at top speed (and noise) to cool when running a game such as Skyrim.

Comment: I've been playing skyrim on my pc and the highest temp my pc managed to get was 95 but when i do alt - tab to check it out it goes to the 70s but I'm going to invest in a liquid cooler that fits my motherboard (the screws don't line up with my motherboard)

Comment: Your existing cooler's screws don't line up with the mainboard? That typically means the cooler isn't designed for use with that CPU and may not be capable of providing enough cooling.

Comment: We couldn't get the liquid cooler on because the screws didn't align with the motherboard, so we invested in a cpu fan instead which was a horrible idea, yesterday when playing a game apparently the temps were 101.2C so I'm not to use the computer anymore until i can get it to cool down or until i get a liquid cooler

Answer (score 1):

95c does sound like a lot. You can look up your CPU model and see the maximum operating temp. You can either crank up the fans in the bios, or you can buy an internal liquid cooling cpu heatsink (what I recommend). They are prebuilt, and you just need to mount it to your case and your cpu. One thing to consider if you are going that route, is to buy one that will fit a common type of socket. So if you plan on upgrading, you can use the heatsink again.

Comment: Can you provide specifics how the author accomplishes your suggestions?

Comment: I have an internal liquid cooling cpu heatsink with 2 fan slots and another one with 1 fan slot and both won't fit in my case. I currently don't know the exact name of my tower but the closes thing I could find to it is Thermaltake Commander G41 Mid-Tower Chassis